# How to append bytes, multi-bytes and buffer to ArrayBuffer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, buffer, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

Javascript ArrayBuffer or TypedArrays dont have any kind of appendByte(), appendBytes(), or appendBuffer() methods. So if I want to fill an ArrayBuffer one value at a time, how do I do it?

```
var firstVal = 0xAB;              // 1 byte
var secondVal = 0x3D7F            // 2 bytes
var anotherUint8Array = someArr;

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer();   // I don't know the length yet
var bufferArr = new UInt8Array(buffer);

// following methods do not exist. What are the alternatives for each??
bufferArr.appendByte(firstVal);
bufferArr.appendBytes(secondVal);
bufferArr.appendBuffer(anotherUint8Array);
```

Comment: it's an array, use array syntax `r[i]=x` ex: https://github.com/rndme/download/blob/master/download.js#L69  also review the syntax for the Uint8Array constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array#Syntax - you need a size on that array buffer to be able to use it like that....

Comment: You can't modify the buffer size after it is created

Answer (score 38):

You can create a new *TypedArray* with a new *ArrayBuffer*, but you can't change the size of an existing buffer

```
function concatTypedArrays(a, b) { // a, b TypedArray of same type
    var c = new (a.constructor)(a.length + b.length);
    c.set(a, 0);
    c.set(b, a.length);
    return c;
}
```

Now can do

```
var a = new Uint8Array(2),
    b = new Uint8Array(3);
a[0] = 1; a[1] = 2;
b[0] = 3; b[1] = 4;
concatTypedArrays(a, b); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 0] Uint8Array length 5
```

If you want to use different types, go via `Uint8Array` as the smallest unit is a *byte*, i.e.

```
function concatBuffers(a, b) {
    return concatTypedArrays(
        new Uint8Array(a.buffer || a), 
        new Uint8Array(b.buffer || b)
    ).buffer;
}
```

This means `.length` will work as expected, you could now convert this to your typed array of choice (make sure it's a type that would accept the `.byteLength` of the buffer though)

---

From here, you could now implement any method you like for concatenating your data, e.g.

```
function concatBytes(ui8a, byte) {
    var b = new Uint8Array(1);
    b[0] = byte;
    return concatTypedArrays(ui8a, b);
}

var u8 = new Uint8Array(0);
u8 = concatBytes(u8, 0x80); // [128]
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul S. It would have been nice for such basic functions to be part of the spec and implemented natively, but your solution is pretty good. One question I still have how would you append a multi-byte, lets say a single 4-byte value to a typedarray. We can loop and call your suggested `concatBytes` function multiple times for each single byte, but can it be accomplished in better way?

Comment: @codneto how are your multi-bytes stored? e.g. if you're using ints, how do you know the difference between `0x3D7F` and `0x00003D7F`? And yes, I agree there should be some native `concat`, but I don't think there should be a native `push` or _length_ changing - that's not how typed arrays work

Comment: S, I have some functions which return 4-byte value which I need to add to buffer. I also am reading some bytes from a stream and appending to buffer, and sometimes based on some flags I have to read 1, 2 or 4 byte value, all of which need to be appended to buffer. How should I accomplish appending these multi-byte values to buffer?

Comment: @codneto write it as a loop. Best place to loop would be creating a `n` long _Uint8Array_ for the new data and using the loop to set the vales on it before concatenating with your previous data.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I changed `concatBytes` as following. I think it will work.



    **function concatBytes(ui8a, bytes) {
        var b = new Uint8Array(bytes.length);
        bytes.forEach(function (byte, index) {
            b[index] = byte;
        });
        return concatTypedArrays(ui8a, b);
    }

    var u8 = new Uint8Array(0);
    // to append 0x80C83B 
    u8 = concatBytes(u8, [0x80, 0xC8, 0x3B]); // 128, 200, 59]**

Comment: Can't post formatted code in comments, therefore code in above comment is not readable so created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pLb3haqr/

Answer (score 9):

Paul's answer allows you to concatenate one TypedArray to an existing TypedArray. In ES6, you can use the following function to concatenate multiple TypedArrays:

```
function concatenate(resultConstructor, ...arrays) {
    let totalLength = 0;
    for (const arr of arrays) {
        totalLength += arr.length;
    }
    const result = new resultConstructor(totalLength);
    let offset = 0;
    for (const arr of arrays) {
        result.set(arr, offset);
        offset += arr.length;
    }
    return result;
}

const ta = concatenate(Uint8Array,
    Uint8Array.of(1, 2), Uint8Array.of(3, 4));
console.log(ta); // Uint8Array [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(ta.buffer.byteLength); // 4
```

To append a new byte is:

```
const byte = 3;
concatenate(Uint8Array, Uint8Array.of(1, 2), Uint8Array.of(byte));
```

This method is found in [ExploringJS](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_typed-arrays.html#sec_typed-arrays).